# Sqlite opened connection for the lifetime of the app

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm building a mobile app and I use SQLite as the data-storage...

And I have two approaches for executing sql-query in my mobile-app

**First** Open a connection to the DB when the app-loads and use it for the lifetime of the app, and close it on-app-close.

**Second** Open a connection per each-query-execution.

What's better in terms of **speed** and **reliability**

Comment: The former is faster by a long shot.

Comment: @Shawn Why does it have a little chance of success ?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the recommendation to use `Room`, I recommend to use the SQLiteOpenHelper. It is a perfect implementation on how to deal with this question. It opens the DB once and uses this instance over the livetime. The helper even recognizes when the instance got closed and reopens it for you:

Have a single instance of the SQL Helper and make this available to all ViewModels (or controllers or whatsoever).
For example you could have a static reference in your MainApp (if you use multiple activities) or in your MainActivity (if you only use one) and then just access it by `MainActivity.getDbHelper()`.

Where you need access you can then call

```
db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase()
// or
db = dbHelper.getWriteableDatabase()
```

and get your cursor by a query() or modify the db with exec()

---

Update:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbName.db";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_YOUR_TABLE_STRING);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... having a single db-instance || connection is reliable?

Comment: It is absolutely reliable, since the SQLiteOpenHelper is exactly made to deal with this. So you habe a single istance of the helper and the helper provides you the db-instance

Comment: Opening the database is costly, hence the helper takes care. If you look into its implementation, it also has a single db-instance

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli if this helped you, please consider to accept the answer to help others finding the answer too.